# Доступ к элементам массива после форматирования

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Делаю в подключаемом модуле(отдельный файл) различные преобразования с данными.
Данные имеют следующий вид:

```
[ 0.00000000e+00  2.57172755e-16 -2.16840434e-19 ... -5.14184397e-01
  6.56365884e-01  9.36825886e-01]
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то для scikit-learn формат данных должен быть в столбик заключенный двумя квадратными скобками? Вот такой:

```
[[ 0.00000000e+00]
 [-1.23707468e-16]
 [ 3.25260652e-19]
 ...
 [-2.82352941e-01]
 [ 3.25688073e-01]
 [ 2.88990826e-01]]
```

Чтобы форматировать массив в нужный использую .reshape(-1, 1), то есть делаю так:

```
X1 = rez[:split].reshape(-1, 1)
X1_ = rez[split:].reshape(-1, 1)
```

1.Теперь собственно вопрос:
хочу форматировать массив в подключаемом файле, то есть после всех 
преобразований применить к нему .reshape(-1, 1).
Но, при попытке обратиться к данным в основном файле так:

```
X1 = rez[:split]
X1_ = rez[split:]
```

получаю ошибку. 
Вывел данные в принты rez.reshape(-1, 1):

```
####print(rez)
[[ 0.00000000e+00]
 [ 3.55271368e-15]
 [-4.00000000e+01]
 ...
 [ 1.33555927e-01]
 [ 1.50417362e+00]
 [ 4.96115427e-01]]
###print(type(rez))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
###print(rez.shape)
(7310, 1)
Сообщения выводятся такие:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/matemat/test3.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(rez.columns)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

print(rez.columns)  не распечатался по всей видимости из-за ошибки.
Предполагаю, что надо как-то по другому получать доступ к элементам?

2.И еще вопрос в описании Python список это данные в одинарных квадратных скобках, через запятую. А у меня данные запятыми не разделяются(данные считываются pd.read_csv с файла). Как это можно понять?

Comment: Поправил сообщение. Ошибки возможно нет. Просто нужно как-то по другому обращаться к списку. Но, у меня не получается. Хотел попрятать основной код в подключаемый модуль, чтобы в основном файле только получались уже рассчитанные данные(признаки) для машинного обучения.

Comment: Вы можете уточнить суть вопроса? Что конкретно у вас не получается? Я так и не понял получаете вы ошибку или нет. Если получаете то какую, если нет то в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Ошибки нет. Мне не понятно, как обращаться к массиву, который располагается в столбик. Когда он был в строку[ 0.00000000e+00  2.57172755e-16 -2.16840434e-19] , то данные получал к примеру так:  rez[:split].

Comment: `rez[:N]` - замечательно работает как для обычных списков так и для Numpy NDArray (ваш случай). Все еще не понимаю с чем у вас возникли трудности... Можете привести в вопросе небольшой __воспроизводимый__ пример с которым у вас возникли трудности/проблемы? Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: Да, Вы были правы) Сейчас свежим взглядом посмотрел на свои коды. Попробовал снова и все заработало.